# bootstrap navbar-fixed-top miss place on mobile when typing in any input field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I have a fix top navbar defined by:`<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">`, and pages that user can edit content with ckeditor. It works fine PC but when using on mobile device the navbar instead of fixed top will be fixed at where it was the moment entering the editing mode. Although the navbar will be back to where it suppose to be once user finish editing, it can be quite annoying since the navbar could happen to overlap ckeditor's toolbar like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QkSz.png).

Well this actually happen on all input field, but more obvious when u got a large input area like textarea.

PS: just in case, it's not the zooming issue which solved by setting input field text font larger than 16px that I am asking.

Update demo code(need to view on phone to see issue, device mode on chrome cant recreate this problem):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>demo</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        </div><!-- navbar-header -->
      </div><!-- end of fluid container -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <body>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="list-group-item">
      <form method="POST" action="/andu/m/share/user/voice">  
        <label for="ft"><span class="text-danger">*</span>content</label>
          <textarea name="text" class="form-control" rows="2" id="ft"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="act" value="save" class="btn btn-success btn-block">save</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the code or demo where we can see the issue as without code/demo we can't help you.

Comment: demo code added, might need to test it on mobile device via your localhost to see the problem.